# Line perpendicular to the maximum axis of an irregular polygon (sinkholes) QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I am performing a morphometric analysis of dolines using QGIS 3. The analysis consists of determining the longest axis (the union of the two most distant points of the polygon) and the shortest axis which is the longest line perpendicular to the major axis and it is inside the polygon.

I could determine the major axis by the distance matrix, as they answered me in [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311306/finding-the-major-axis-of-a-polygon-the-outline-of-a-sinkhole-or-doline), but I have not been able to find the line perpendicular to this one.

[image]

Comment: not sure if I understood your question correctly, but maybe a ready-made solution will solve your question...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295648/the-longest-straight-line-l-within-a-polygon-and-the-longest-perpendicular-lin/307102#307102

Comment: hello, is exactly what I need to calculate, but I do not understand well how to select the points to make the Delaunay triangulation and generate the line perpendicular to the major axis (line L)

Comment: I added a fragment of the picture with the image of the map object selection tool...when you select a point, it should be highlighted in yellow...

Comment: If I understand the method @Cyril recommended, you need points on the boundary of the polygon. You can extract them with the `extract vertices` tool. If you need more points than just the vertices, you can use one of the `densify` tools to add more vertices, then extract vertices again.

Comment: together, with csk we will definitely help Johny and lead him to victory ...:-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I already managed to generate the triangle delaunay but the line (T) is not perpendicular to (L), I think it will depend on the point that I select to generate the triangle. Am I right, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: This method is more manual and will depend on your choice of points. In principle, the extreme opposite points should be perpendicular if your pits do not have an elongated and complex shape ...

Comment: Look at this post at the beginning, I think it is more understandable: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264416/splitting-overlap-between-polygons-and-assign-to-nearest-polygon-using-postgis/283047#283047

Comment: You can also create tsetroids for polygons and use this point as well ...

Comment: helo @Cyril, because some polygons have very irregular shapes, the location of the points assigned to perform the triangulation is very subjective. I already managed to generate the perpendicular lines using the Shape tools >> create line of bearing plugin, taking into account the angle of orientation calculated previously to the line L (angle L + 90 °)

Comment: I'm glad you've solved your problem...: -)...